# How do I set up a Spring MVC view resolver for a javascript resource?

Tags: spring-mvc

**I generate javascript using a Spring MVC controller as follows:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="path/to/handler", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces ="text/javascript")
public ModelAndView getJs(HttpServletRequest request) {
  String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
  return new ModelAndView("/path/to/js/", "contextPath", contextPath);
}
```

I am not sure how to set up the view resolver for the javascript resource though. Can someone please advise how to set up the view resolver for a js resource?

Answer (score 0):

you can place your js file in

```
src/main/webapp/resources/js/somefile.js
```

add this to your servlet-context.xml

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<resources location="/resources/favicon.ico" mapping="/favicon.ico"/>
```

and now you can access your .js file by:
localhost:8080/yourapp/resources/js/somefile.js

Comment: you can also map favicon.ico and other resources (like images etc) as shown above...

Comment: Do you mean to say that I don't need a view resolver when I generate a JS resource from Spring?